# approach to reload Complete state of application?

Tags: android

i have a question which i know its answers vary from one app to another.

consider an app like Telegram which you have a noticeably amount of data there like your contacts and chats. when you close the app and later you relaunch that, even if you don't have any connection to internet, app loads your contacts and chats and this is done in fraction of second. i want to know how these works are done and implemented?

for example they store all the data in disk in a file(storing that amount of data on disk can take long time moreover they cache images too), or we save each part of app in different files and we load them whenever user opens them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two commonly used ways to store data in Android. `SharedPreferences` and local databases.

Before I continue, you should check out other articles regarding storing data on android. There are loads of them explaining it better and in-depth than what I can, I will just give some examples what you can use.

[Start here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) or just google it!

### SharedPreferences

SharedPreferences works in a `Key -> Value`, used for saving basic types of data. Good for storing user tokens, settings and similar things.

[See more](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

### Databases

Android uses SQLite for local data storage, and there are many libraries that can help you with this.

More notably [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), but there are other ones as well that are very popular to use. Databases are good for storing large amounts of data, like conversations and contacts in the example you are talking about.

### Caching

You also have access to caching data, but keep in mind that it's meant as a temporary storage, and if you want to store something like user information or other complex data, you should stick to a database. Caching is useful for images.

Comment: hey man tnx for answer but saving files is not my issue. im searching for a suitable approach to manage how to reload my app each time user rerun that.

Comment: If you have a lot of data that you need to save, like conversations and contacts in the example of Telegram, then I would recommend you to go with a simple database :) Look into Room, I linked it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is called api data caching. It is important that we should know which data to be cached and which data should not be cached.

There is a library from [NYtimes](https://github.com/NYTimes/Store) you can use it for api level caching with retrofit.

[image]